# template class with Non-type template Parameter member function

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I am trying to define a specialization of a template class which contains a Non-type template Parameter member function. And I get the following error:

```
error: too few template-parameter-lists

Here's a sample class that describes the problem in brief,
// file.h
template <typename T>
class ClassA {
  T Setup();
  template <int K> static void Execute();
};

//file.cc
void ClassA<int>::Execute<2>() { //Do stuff    }
```

I believe this is more of a syntax issue than a design issue, any clues? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if you fully specialize a template, you still need `template<>`:

```
template<> template<> void ClassA<int>::Execute<2>() { //Do stuff    }
```

Comment: Well, that throws the error
error: template-id 'Execute<2>' for 'void ClassA<int>::Execute()' does not match any template declaration

Comment: That's because it needs to say `template<>` twice (once for the class and once for the function) as noted in my answer.

Comment: Whoops, missed the function template. Thanks, @MarkB

Comment: yep, need to add that twice, interesting. Thanks Dark

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to tell the compiler that you're specializing a template method of a template class:

```
template <>
template <>
void ClassA<int>::Execute<2>()
{
    //Do stuff
}
```